# How to use prebuilt c++ library for android ndk project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am a android NDK newbie, I am trying to follow the documentation at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts and I found it is unclear on how to setup the code.
So to declare a prebuilt library, it shows the first step:

> Give the module a name. This name does not need to be the same as that
> of the prebuilt library, itself.

**Question 1:** What does this mean by giving the module a name? rename the module folder? is this the folder usually called `jni/`? does it matter where this folder should be?

**Question 2:** If I don't find this `jni/` folder, should I just add one by creating a new folder or right clicked on my project in android studio to add new module? I did the right click thing and there is no such module for native c++ libs.

the second step:

> In the module's Android.mk file, assign to LOCAL_SRC_FILES ...

**Question 3:** Should I create the 1Android.mk` file by myself? if it is a must, why not have it generated automatically?

I then tried to follow the documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#new-project but there is no such `Android.mk` file created...
Anyway, in the `Android.mk` file it has something like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo-user
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo-user.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Question 4:** On the documentation page, where variables like `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` is defined? can these path can be any place in the system as long I define it with full path?

**Question 5:** for `LOCAL_PATH`, I understand it is the local path where the `Android.mk` file locates, does that mean 1) the system will find this file automatically, 2) I can only have one folder with `Android.mk` if I want to use native libs?

Comment: If you're using `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` your source file should be a .so file, not a .c file, and `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` should not be present. Also, don't bundle multiple questions into one stackoverflow question.

Comment: As far as documentation go, see https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts and https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk

Comment: Found the same situation and had the same questions. Why has nobody responded? The offical documentation is not good for a total Android NDK beginner (but C++ and CMake developer for decades).